# C# exe not working on target platform x86

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, process, database-connection, target-platform

so, I'm trying to log accesses to my shared files on the network (I'm modifying [Abdollah Zawari's ShareMoniter](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/62357/Monitoring-Access-to-Your-Shared-Files-on-Network)), i do this by starting openfiles.exe like so:

```
        var process = new Process();
        process.StartInfo.FileName = "openfiles.exe";
        process.StartInfo.Arguments = "/query /FO CSV /v";
        process.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
        process.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
        process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
        try
        {
            process.Start();
            if ((process.StandardOutput != null))
            {
                var result = process.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd().Trim().Replace("\"", "");
                var lines = result.Split('\n');...
```

I want to log the results in an Access database, but jet.Oledb.4.0 or ace.oledb.12.0 only work when I set the project's target platform to x86.

problem is, openfiles.exe doesn't return anything when i run the project for x86 (openfiles.exe starts and ends with no apparent error, but an empty string "" is returned)

I'm very much a newbie, especially in these fields, so any advice on the matter would be greatly appreciated

thanks in advence

Comment: Did you try to set the target platform to: **Any CPU**?

Comment: yes, any target platform other than x86 results in an error "the microsoft.ace.oledb.4.0 provider is not registered on the local machine"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The version of the Oledb you are using does not support 64bit, you need to use a newer version that works on both 32 & 64 bit. Use the [Microsoft Access Database Engine 2010](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=13255) instead to access the database and things will be fine.